# How to select the given option in dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I've a dropdown

```
<select id="ddl1">
    <option value="0">number</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
</select>
```

now what i'm doing is as soon as user clicks on `ddl1` i change its default value to `4` like this

```
$(function () {

    var defaultValue = "4";

    $('#ddl1').click(function () {
        var select_val = $('#ddl1').val();

        if (select_val == "0")
            $('#ddl1').val(defaultValue);
    });
});
```

but now the problem is when user tries to select the default option of dropdown i.e `number`, option `4` is selected. Any ideas how to fix this?

The problem is when the user just clicks on dropdown -> option`4` must be selected and when user clicks on option `number` -> option `number` must be selected instead of option `4`.

Comment: can you tell us your desired functionality? like what you actually want it to do?

Comment: @indubitablee : when the user just clicks on dropdown -> option`4` must be selected and when user clicks on option `number` -> option `number` must be selected instead of option `4`... updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you're doing that but `focusin` or `focus` events can help you achieve that as follows:

```js
$(function() {
    $('#ddl1').on('focusin', function() {
        this.value != 0 || $(this).val( 4 );
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="ddl1">
    <option value="0">number</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks this is what i was looking for.. but can you please explain what this line does `this.value != 0 || $(this).val( 4 );`

Comment: That's just a *fancy* way of writing `if( this.value == 0 ) { $(this).val( 4 ); }` .... it takes advantage of the fact that in an `OR` expression only one operand needs to be true for the expression to be true, therefore `$(this).val( 4 )` is evaluated ***ONLY WHEN*** `this.value != 0` is `false`.

Comment: okies :) , thanks a ton mate for the answer and explanation..wish i could give you double upvote :p :D

Comment: You're welcome! Thank you so much for your feedback; glad I could be of help.

Answer (score 1):

You should call this function on `change`, not `click` - else, like you said, as soon as you click an option is selected.

```
$('#ddl1').change(function () {
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/88h74ezm/)

Edit: You should use a class to give the feel of the default option, you don't actually want it set to selected EACH time the user clicks:

```
<select id="ddl1">
    <option value="0">number</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4" class="default">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
</select>

.default {
    color: blue;
}
```

Comment: So you want the option highlighted when you click the dropdown? @SidM

Comment: when the user just clicks on dropdown -> option`4` must be selected and when user clicks on option `number` -> option `number` must be selected instead of option `4`.. updated the question

Comment: @SidM -- See my edit, use a class on the default option.

Comment: highlighting it blue doesnt select the option. OP wants it selected automatically when you first click on the select @SidM see my solution

Comment: @indubitablee: she? o_o

Answer (score 1):

is this what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/84/

```
$(function () {
    var defaultValue = "4";
    var count = 0;
    $('#ddl1').click(function () {
        if (count < 1) {
            $('#ddl1').val(defaultValue);
            count++;
        }        
    });
});
```

Comment: Applying a count check is not the right way of doing it.